# What are these element called?

Tags: java, android, instagram

I'm developing my first real app and found inspiration in Instagrams design.

[image]

I would like to know what the red and blue area is called and if these exist within androids own libraries so I can implement them.

I guessing that the blue area is something called carousel list/tab-list or button menu or maybe a lot of radio buttons? If you, for example, press on the Juno filter, the list will automatically scroll towards left, so you can see the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red rectangle is `horizontalscrollview` and the blue rectangle is `LinearLayout` with three child.

Comment: Is the HorizontalScrollView a TabPane? Would you suggest to implement it as tabpane or radiogroup?

Comment: Use `HorizontalScrollView`. Its a standard view of `android`

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple options but I think the blue box in LinearLayout and Red one might be a simple scrollview

Comment: So the scrollview in this example contains radiobuttons?